# Kotlin: How to iterate over the list from specific index?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to dynamically iterate over the list from specific index with dynamic end of the iteration.

Example: If I have List and there are 8 elements in it(thats static it will always be 8) and I pass index 5, I want to iterate that list from index 5 to index 5 (5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4).

Comment: _"from index 5 to index 5"_ So you want to get a single element..?

Comment: Yeah, but I want to iterate as it would be infinite list, so forEach will not stop at lastIndex which is 7 but it will continue to 0 until it reaches specified index.

Comment: You mean you want to treat it like a circular buffer that you iterate forever until `break` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use remainder as index

```
val list = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val offset = 5
for (ix in list.indices) {
    println(list[(ix + offset) % list.size]) // <- starts at 0 when ix + offset is greater then size of the list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may shift items by the desired offset

`Collections.rotate(list, -5)`

And then iterate